# Full count of distinct elements of a column efficiently

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, distinct, window-functions

Need to select multiple rows having the same value in a column along with full count of the distinct values with pagination on the distinct values.
But would like to avoid taking distinct count using`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(dept_name)) FROM data_set` as it would scan all the records.

In the below example I'm using `row_no` for fetching multiple records according to the pagination and in the application layer I would be grouping `dept_a -> LIST<name,age>`. Also need full count to decide the number of potential pages present.

Is there a way to get the full count using window functions or any other way efficiently in postgres?

Table:

```
 dept_name |  name  | age
-----------+--------+-----
 dept_a    | name11 |  10
 dept_a    | name12 |  11
 dept_a    | name13 |  10
 dept_a    | name14 |  12
 dept_a    | name15 |  11
 dept_b    | name21 |  10
 dept_b    | name22 |  11
 dept_b    | name23 |  10
 dept_b    | name24 |  12
 dept_b    | name25 |  11
```

Expected output:

```
 dept_name |  name  | age | row_no | count
-----------+--------+-----+--------+-------
 dept_a    | name11 |  10 |      1 |     2
 dept_a    | name12 |  11 |      1 |     2
 dept_a    | name13 |  10 |      1 |     2
 dept_a    | name14 |  12 |      1 |     2
 dept_a    | name15 |  11 |      1 |     2
```

Query that would give the result but need to use `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(dept_name)) FROM data_set`.
`count(1) OVER () AS full_count` , gives the full count as `10` as it considers all the rows and not the `distinct` of `dept_name`.

```
WITH row_no_tab AS (
  SELECT *, 
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (
      ORDER BY 
        ds.dept_name
    ) AS row_no 
  FROM data_set ds
) 
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  row_no_tab 
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(dept_name)) FROM data_set
  ) AS distinct_count 
WHERE 
  row_no > 0 
  AND row_no <= 1
```

Comment: Just a side note: `distinct` is not a function. Enclosing the expression after the keyword in parentheses is useless.

Comment: Sorry, but i did not understand the rule of grouping and counting. Do you want to get unique combinations of `dept_name`, `name` and `age`, count of unique `dept_name` + `name` as `row_no` and count of unique `dept_name` + `age`? And why all  the rows have a `count` value 2?

Comment: @alexey ```row_no``` is being used as pagination here. It gives the same values to the identical ```dept_name```.
On top of this I need ```full_count``` of distinct ```dept_name``` in the table. Which would tell us how many total records are present to show the number of pages in the UI.
Just fyi, we would pair the ```dept_name``` to the list of ```name```, ```age``` in the application layer.
We just need the output in the form I have mentioned under 'Expected output'. And what we see in the expected o/p is for page-1.
For page-2 it would be queried as ```row_no > 1 and row_no<=2```